# Cut & Paste Overwriting Range Object definitions

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I've found an interesting problem with Excel VBA's Cut and paste involving the use of a defined Range Object.

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
Sub PasteToRangeDoesntWork()
Dim StRng As Range
Dim j, k, x, y As Integer

Set StRng = Range("A3")
x = 0
j = Range(StRng, StRng.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
k = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(StRng, StRng.End(xlDown)))

For y = 1 To k
    While StRng.Offset(x, 0) = y
        x = x + 1
    Wend
    If y < k Then
        Range(StRng.Offset(x, 0), StRng.End(xlDown).Offset(o, j - 1)).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Set StRng = StRng.Offset(0, j + 1)
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=StRng
        x = 0
    End If
Next y
End Sub
```

The problem is that when pasting to the defined `StRng`, the `StRng` object disappears and becomes and undefined object.

There's a simple fix, which I've done below.

```
Sub PasteToRangeWorks()
Dim StRng As Range
Dim j, k, x, y As Integer

Set StRng = Range("A3")
x = 0
j = Range(StRng, StRng.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
k = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(StRng, StRng.End(xlDown)))

For y = 1 To k
    While StRng.Offset(x, 0) = y
        x = x + 1
    Wend
    If y < k Then
        Range(StRng.Offset(x, 0), StRng.End(xlDown).Offset(o, j - 1)).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Set StRng = StRng.Offset(0, j)
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=StRng.Offset(0, 1)
        Set StRng = StRng.Offset(0, 1)
        x = 0
    End If
Next y
End Sub
```

This works -- i.e. by not pasting the new cells directly to the `StRng` and instead to `StRng.offset(0,1)`, the `StRng` object remains defined.

The Data in question are five columns across. The first column is an integer (with values going from 1 to 7), the next column is text followed by a column with dates and finally, two columns of general format data (2 decimal points).

The fix is not difficult but I'm perplexed as to why the first code doesn't work. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: You probably have a typo in your code; StRng.End(xlDown).Offset(o, j - 1) contains an 'o' (small letter), which is an undefined name.  Have you used Option Explicit?  If not, better start using it now to catch these types of errors and replace the '0' with a zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the .Paste method, then all defined ranges that fall withing the paste boundaries will be reset.  The exact "Why?" is something only Microsoft can explain I'm afraid.

A better alternative is to work with the Range.Value and Range.Clear members; these won't cause this issue, are faster, and also don't mess with the clipboard.  Note however that this only copies the values and not the formatting nor any formulas.

The code for this can be something like this:

```
  Dim SourceRng As Range
  Set SourceRng = Range(StRng.Offset(x, 0), StRng.End(xlDown).Offset(0, j - 1))
  Set StRng = StRng.Offset(0, j + 1)
  Dim DestRng As Range
  Set DestRng = StRng.Resize(SourceRng.Rows.Count, SourceRng.Columns.Count)
  DestRng.Value = SourceRng.Value
  Call SourceRng.Clear
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestions worked very well.